# Android App I made won't Install but works fine in emulator?

Tags: android, installation, apk

I'm having an issue installing an exported, unsigned .apk on my android device. I have an HTC Droid Incredible 2 and can't get my apk to install. Whenever I try to with the Astro File Manager app or AppInstaller app it prompts me for the install and everything, says the permissions it uses, and then when I hit the "Install" button it shows the loading bar for about half a second and then says "Application not installed" and I have no way to debug or anything on my phone because the Incredible 2 will not connect to my PC no matter what I enable or try and it won't show on adb.

Here's a copy of my Manifest, is there anything that could be causing an install issue, or something I left out? It runs on my emulator with 0 problems.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.slammednavigator"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
    />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="4"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"     />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SlammedNavigatorActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name="org.apache.cordova.DroidGap" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
            <intent-filter> 
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: There are also several apps that you can install which will show you  the logcat and thus, the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sign your .apk file or else Android won't install it. When you are running it on the emulator, or a device through eclipse, the .apk is signed with a certain debug certificate which allows installation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled the Unknown Source in your mobile device. As you are installing unsigned apk you have to enable the Unknown Source. To enable go to settings -> Applications -> check the Unknown source in the list -> click on ok button.